# Query string and use that value to influence the targetted column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage that I want to be show in different language when changing the query string, ie; `mypage.php?langue=en_en`

I'm able to do it with the code I found from bumperbox:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39787/multi-language-website-management

I change the code to be able to make the language selection with a query string:

Original code

```
class lang {

    private $lang = null;

    function __construct($lang) {
        $this->lang = parse_ini_file("{$lang}.ini");
    }


    public function xlate($str) {

        $arg_count = func_num_args();

        if ($arg_count > 1) {
            $params = func_get_args();

            // strip first arg
            array_shift($params);
        } else {
            $params = array();
        }

        $out_str = isset($this->lang[$str]) ? $this->lang[$str] : null;

        // if you string doesn't exist or is mistyped, then blow up, so we know about it
        // or you could even go away to google translate and perform the translation for
        // any missing strings
        if (!$out_str) {
            throw new exception("Lang String Not Found: $str");
        }

        return vsprintf($out_str, $params);
    }
}

$lang = new lang('fr_fr');
```

I have changed the last line:

```
$lang = new lang('fr_fr');
```

for :

```
$lang = new lang(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['langue']));
```

So I can select the language (`fr_fr` or `en_en`) from the url with `mypage.php/langue=fr_fr`

This works well.

My issue is that I would like to show a different column in my sqlquery depending of that query string.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    if($lang == "fr_fr"){
        $tmpTarget="code_produit"; 
    }
    else {
        $tmpTarget="product_code";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>$row[$tmpTarget]</td></tr>"
```

This doesn't work, it always bring me back the else result even if my language selection is french.

I tried several things but nothing worked so far. I really don't know what else to do. I simply need that if $lang = the selection made in the query string, then my tmpTarget would be a different value so I can show the french name of the product code which is in a different column in my table.

Thank you in advance for your help!!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Start by echoing `$lang` just before the `if($lang == "fr_fr")` to see if it contains what you expect. If that piece of code is in a function you need to use `global $lang;`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply KIKO, when I do echo $lang, I got 'Array' as a result.

Comment: Then use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to see if the language is in the array, and change the if condition accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lang = new lang('fr_fr');
```

sets `$lang` to an object, not a string. You need to add code to your `lang` class that returns the name of the language.

```
class lang {

    private $lang = null;
    public $name;

    function __construct($lang) {
        $this->lang = parse_ini_file("{$lang}.ini");
        $this->name = $lang;
    }


    public function xlate($str) {

        $arg_count = func_num_args();

        if ($arg_count > 1) {
            $params = func_get_args();

            // strip first arg
            array_shift($params);
        } else {
            $params = array();
        }

        $out_str = isset($this->lang[$str]) ? $this->lang[$str] : null;

        // if you string doesn't exist or is mistyped, then blow up, so we know about it
        // or you could even go away to google translate and perform the translation for
        // any missing strings
        if (!$out_str) {
            throw new exception("Lang String Not Found: $str");
        }

        return vsprintf($out_str, $params);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
if ($lang->name == "fr_fr") {
    $tmpTarget = "code_produit";
} else {
    $tmpTarget = "product_code";
}
```

BTW, I would put that `if` statement before the `while` loop, since the condition doesn't change for each row.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly Barmar!! Really appreciate your help and thanks for the heads up on the if sttement before while, make a lot of sense! :) Wish I could click upvote but since I just registered it seems like I can't for now :(